# How to use numeric literals with num::Integer types?

Tags: generics, rust

I'm trying to write some numerically templated functions and I'm finding a number of stumbling blocks. One I recently found is the following code:

```
extern crate num;
use num::Integer;
use num::Zero;

fn f<T: Integer>() -> T {
    T::zero() + 1
}

fn main() {
    let x: u32 = f();
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

This doesn't work, because `1` is a "mismatched type" and the compiler "expected type parameter, found integral variable".

Now, I know that `T::zero() + T::one()` does work and "fixes" the above problem, but what if I use numeric literals for which there is nothing like `Zero`, like 2, 10, 100?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`FromPrimitive`](https://docs.rs/num/0.1.41/num/trait.FromPrimitive.html) or [`Num::from_str_radix`](https://docs.rs/num/0.1.41/num/trait.Num.html#tymethod.from_str_radix) seems to match your need.

```
extern crate num;
use num::{Integer, FromPrimitive};

fn f<T: Integer + FromPrimitive>() -> T {
    T::zero() + T::from_i32(1).unwrap()
}

fn main() {
    let x: u32 = f();
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

or

```
extern crate num;
use num::Integer;

fn f<T: Integer>() -> T {
    T::zero() + T::from_str_radix("1", 10).ok().unwrap()
}

fn main() {
    let x: u32 = f();
    println!("{}", x);
}
```